# Add always constraint to route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.Net Mvc and I'm so confused about routing configurations. After I deployed my project to production requirements changed about urls. First version of my application my routing configuration was like below

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                        );
```

But customer wanted to access application like `"http://{serveraddress}/ClaimFilePortal/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. After this I have changed my routing config like below.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        url: "{applicationname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { applicationname ="ClaimFilePortal",controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                        constraints:new {applicationname = "ClaimFilePortal"}
                        );
```

But in controllers' code there are redirections like and mvc not adding `"ClaimFilePortal"` constraint.

```
        return RedirectToAction("Index2", "Account",
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { systemUserId = systemUserId, returnUrl = "/Upload/RedirectToFolder" + Request.Url.Query}));
```

So, how can I add a configuration for all redirections `(Redirect(), RedirectToAction(), RedirectToRoute() etc.)` to add my constraints before all urls.

Comment: If you are required to have the prefix `ClaimFilePortal` then you could map your route to `ClaimFilePortal/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.. But the constraint will not be able, because it it used to filter the url. You might be able just adding default values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_4

Comment: But in my controllers there are some routings like ` return RedirectToAction("Index2", "Account",
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new { systemUserId = systemUserId, returnUrl = "/Upload/RedirectToFolder" + Request.Url.Query}));` . I don't want to change anything for these situations. Will prefix change url of redirections like this ?

Comment: When I add prefix there is 403.14 error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add 'ClaimFilePortal' as default prefix, remove the {} from it and try like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        url: "applicationname/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { applicationname ="ClaimFilePortal",controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                        constraints:new {applicationname = "ClaimFilePortal"}
                        );
```